# Test if any element of a vector equals 1

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the find operator in Matlab as a boolean and Im wondering if its even possible, if so how so?

This is what I am trying to do

```
//If The second column in X contains a 1, do something
if(find(X(:,2) == 1) == true)
//do something
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html?refresh=true) function:

```
if(any(X(:,2) == 1))
//do something
```

You could achieve something like this using `find`, I wouldn't recommend it though. Here is one option:

```
if(numel(find(X(:,2) == 1)) > 0)
```